# Unable to configure CkEditor in 5.29.1

Tags: ckeditor

In CiviCRM > Administer CiviCRM > Display Preferences (/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1) there's a Configure CKEditor button that does nothing.

CKEditor is stripping out certain style declarations. I want to be able to have simple declaration for adaptive images and the system won't let me.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Is there any JS error on browser console? Can you go to editor link directly? (civicrm/admin/ckeditor?reset=1)

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the prompt reply - I wasn't expecting that! How can I allow a width: 100% declaration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any JS error on browser console? Can you go to editor link directly? (civicrm/admin/ckeditor?reset=1)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long t get back - yes, there's the following error upon clicking the button:

Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at crm-ckeditor-default.js?0=362144001600958432&t=K24B:2
(anonymous) @ crm-ckeditor-default.js?0=362144001600958432&t=K24B:2

But using the civicrm/admin/ckeditor?reset=1 link, I am able to get in. But I can't figure out how to stop the editor from stripping tags. I'd switch to TinyMCE, but that doesn't seem to be an option for 5.x. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!